# nutch job is failing Failed with exit value 255

Tags: nutch

When I run the nutch job for 1 million URLs the nutch job is failing
with

```
20/10/14 12:40:34 ERROR fetcher.Fetcher: Fetcher: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fetcher job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: Task failed task_1601725692999_0307_m_000004
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.fetch(Fetcher.java:500)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.Fetcher.main(Fetcher.java:514)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:158)

Error running:
  /home/hadoop/apache-nutch-1.17/runtime/deploy/bin/nutch fetch -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=2048 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx2048m -Dmapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=2048 -Dmapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx2048m -Dmapreduce.job.reduces=12 -Dmapreduce.reduce.speculative=false -Dmapreduce.map.speculative=false -Dmapreduce.map.output.compress=true -D fetcher.timelimit.mins=300 s3a://pt-test-1/nutch/1million-crawls//segments/20201014115727 -threads 400
Failed with exit value 255.
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the failure is show in the logs of task_1601725692999_0307_m_000004. It's also shown in the task table in the Hadoop UI.

The most likely reason:
`-Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=2048 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx2048m`
mapreduce.map.memory.mb must be larger than the Java heap memory. I'd recommend to add 512 MB to mapreduce.map.memory.mb.

Comment: when I see the yarn logs of that application it is not showing any error.

Comment: The reason must be given in the logs. Since already the first map task failed (`failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0`), it's likely that this task even does not make it to even open a task log. But there must be a hint: have you dumped all log files (eg. `yarn logs -applicationId application_mmm_nn --size_limit_mb -1`)?

Comment: I read one of the website mapreduce.map.java.opts=container*0.8 that is 2048*0.8=1639.May I know the what should be the AM RAM value  and is it necessary to keep the 1 map task to 2 reducers and what should be the reducer ram value.Thanks @Sebastian nagel.